# label text is displaying at wrong place when typing

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-textformfield

As the image is shown below, the first image displays my text field before I click on it. the second image displays how it displays when after start typing and clicking on it. I want to remove that label text display while typing. how can I do that?

[image]

```dart
TextFormField(
  controller: usernameEditingController,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      fillColor: textWhite,
      filled: true,
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        borderSide: const BorderSide(
          color: textdarkBlue,
        ),
      ),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        borderSide: const BorderSide(
          color: textdarkBlue,
        ),
      ),
      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
      ),
      focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
      ),
      isDense: true,
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 30, 10, 0),
      labelText: "User Name",
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 15,
        color: textdarkBlue,
      ),
      hintText: "ex: James",
      hintStyle: TextStyle(
          color: textdarkBlue,
          fontFamily: "Paralucent",
          fontSize: 14)),
  style: TextStyle(
    color: textdarkBlue,
  ),
  validator: (text) {
    if (text!.isEmpty) {
      return "Username can't be empty";
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  },
  onChanged: (String? text) {
    userName = text!;
    //print(userName);
  },
),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is displaying as `OutlineInputBorder`'s behavior.
There are few different ways, One is using `FocusNode`, goal is to provide `labelText:null` on focus change.

```dart
 String userName = "";

  late FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode()
    ..addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });

.....
TextFormField(
  // controller: usernameEditingController,
  focusNode: focusNode,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: focusNode.hasFocus ? null : "User Name",
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the behaviour of `labelText` property if you don't want it , simply remove it and use hintText instead

```
TextFormField(
  controller: usernameEditingController,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      fillColor: textWhite,
      filled: true,
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        borderSide: const BorderSide(
          color: textdarkBlue,
        ),
      ),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        borderSide: const BorderSide(
          color: textdarkBlue,
        ),
      ),
      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
      ),
      focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
      ),
      isDense: true,
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 30, 10, 0),
      
      hintText: "ex: James",
      hintStyle: TextStyle(
          color: textdarkBlue,
          fontFamily: "Paralucent",
          fontSize: 14)),
  style: TextStyle(
    color: textdarkBlue,
  ),
  validator: (text) {
    if (text!.isEmpty) {
      return "Username can't be empty";
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  },
  onChanged: (String? text) {
    userName = text!;
    //print(userName);
  },
),
```